# How do I increase the pagination limit in cakephp scaffolding?

Tags: cakephp

I am using scaffolding in cakePHP. The default view shows me maximum of 20 records.

How can I increase the limit of records to show?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaffolding is nice to test your relation, I think you use this :

```
class CustomNameController extends AppController {
    public $scaffold;
}
```

But If you find yourself really wanting to customize your logic and your views, it’s time to pull your scaffolding down in order to write some code. CakePHP’s bake console is a great because it generates all the code that would produce the same result as the most current scaffold.

Look at : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html.

After that you have to put on your new "CustomNameController":

```
public $components = array('Paginator');

public $paginate = array(
   'limit' => 25, // or more if you want !
);
```

Other solutions is to change:

```
public $settings = array(
    'page' => 1,
    'limit' => 20,
    'maxLimit' => 100,
    'paramType' => 'named'
);
```

on [PaginatorComponent.php](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/PaginatorComponent.php) or extend [Scaffold.php](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Scaffold.php) directly on the CakePHP Lib.